# Google App Engine - "Please use https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin instead." error

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, authentication, go, google-authentication

I am getting a weird error in my Google App Engine Go app. When I prompt the user to log in, they are redirected to a login screen for Google. After logging in, they get a message

> Please use https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin instead.

I haven't touched my app's code in a few months and it wasn't an issue before. My login code is basically what one can see in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/overview). I can easily recreate this error in both Chrome and Firefox and on multiple accounts.

The app can be viewed [here](https://furstore.appspot.com/) (NSFW-ish), login button is on every page.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be a bug on our side. I'd recommend you file a bug report on [our issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), hopefully with some more details like the URL where you see that message, app-id, etc.